# C++ - How to test Factory without dynamic_cast<>

Tags: c++, c++11, tdd

Let's assume I have a class Node declared similarly as follows:

```
class Node{
public:
    template <typename Functor, typename... Args>>
    Node(Functor functor, Args...);
    void process();

private:
// placeholder etc.
};
```

Generally class is meant to bind `Functor` with arguments and launch it with `process` method.

Now let's assume We have got a Factory:

```
class Factory{
public:
Node getConfiguredNode(Settings settings);
};
```

Now the problem is, that I have no possible way to test `getConfiguredNode` method, as I do not know what `Functor` type is stored underhood.

In regular way testing Factories is like:

```
class AbstractClass{
public:
    virtual void doSomething(arguments...) = 0;
};

class Factory{
public:
    AbstractClass& getConfiguredItem(Settings settings)
};

void testCase{

    try{
        dynamic_cast<ExpectedConcreteType&>(factory.getConfiguredItem(settings));
        success();
    }
    catch(...){
         fail()
    }
}
```

I would like to have something like this, that would suit given example.

I could add `getStoredTypeInfo` method, but It would serve for testing purposes only, which is not good from engineering point of view, so my question is:

How can I (if I can) properly test such a factory, with respect to all engineering aspects?

Comment: You may indirectly test with `process` behavior.

Comment: Yes I can do it, but again it is poor practice, as I want to test direcly behavior of Factory and not indirectly test Factory by derectly testing behavior of Node. Moreover Functor itself is tested in different Unit Test, so my test would fail anytime, that Functor's test also fails.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you register types to the factory, one option could be to template your Factory class so that it can return "Test" types instead of "Node" types.

This would keep the registration of functor types consistent, while allowing you to instantiate a new object type only within your test harness.

```
Factory<Node> myNodeFactory;
```

It is up to you whether to:

- encapsulate the node in the test

  ```
  Factory<Test> myTestFactory;  // Test object holds an instantiated Node
  ```
- return a pair of node and test

  ```
  Factory< std::pair<Node,Test> > myTestFactory;
  ```
- construct the node and the test from two factory instances

  ```
  Factory<Node> myNodeFactory;
  Factory<Test> myTestFactory;  // Test receives a Node instance to test
  ```

Comment: Hmmmm, now that I read your question more carefully, it appears you want to test the factory itself, rather than the behaviour of the resulting node.  I will delete this answer if not applicable to your situation.  Maybe you can explain a bit more about exactly what behaviour you need to test.

Comment: How is `Functor` selected by the factory when constructing `Node`?  It seems this abstraction is the reason why your `dynamic_cast` pattern cannot be used.  The factory always creates `Node`, so that's not an issue.  The real thing to test is that the factory selects `Functor`.  Can you adapt my suggestion of templating the factory such that the factory-constructed `Test` can perform construction-time type-checks and set a pass/fail state (possibly validating arguments), e.g. `Factory<Test<ExpectedFunctor>>`?  Your factory would be one-shot, but that might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: I think I quite do not understand your proposition. You mean to make my Factory a template? Even if I do not need it in my production code? If so I guess I would prefer, that Node could return `typeid()` of Stored Functor and compare it. But both solutions affect my production code for testing purposes.

Comment: You have opened yourself up to this problem by using a pattern where a factory always creates the same type.  It appears that inside the factory there is essentially another factory that determines `Functor` and arguments.  Maybe you can abstract that logic into something unit-testable so that `Factory` itself just wraps that behaviour.  Then it's easier to argue that the production code isn't driven quite as much by the testing... Even though this will affect how your production code is laid out.

Comment: Not exactly. Inside the factory, there are three types that can be returned, those are 3 Functors with different argument number and types. To make it one type I bind them to the arguments, and more or less this is how I get a Node.